# Как узнать, успешно ли произведён экспорт с помощью mysqldump?

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте!
Запускаю из php mysqldump с нужными параметрами, создается файл, всё ок, но как узнать, действительно ли всё прошло успешно? Ведь мало ли какие сбои произойдут?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дамп делается в консольном режиме через вывод SQL-скрипта на STDOUT. Этот вывод перенаправляется в файл, и, если на каком-то этапе произойдет сбой или обрыв связи, то этот файл не допишится до конца. Как вариант можно проверить файл на наличие `Dump completed` в последней строке.

Концовка дамп файла в сгенеренного через `mysqldump` выглядит так:

```
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2012-04-12 16:58:52
```

Comment: спасиб, не заметил!

Comment: что интересно, мой mysqldump создает файл без этой последней строки..)))

Comment: Вероятнее всего это зависит от версии утилиты `mysqldump`.
У меня:

    mysqldump  Ver 10.13 Distrib 5.1.57, for Win32 (ia32)

Посмотри на индивидуальные особенности последней части дампа сгенеренного твоим `mysqldump`-ом, и отталкивайся от них.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью [file_exists()](http://www.php.ru/manual/function.file-exists.html) проверить наличие создаваемого файла с дампом

Comment: хм, но ведь при запуске mysqldump создается пустой файл, а дальше если какойто сбой, то этот пустой файл и остается, тоесть если проверить file_exists() файл то существует, но верные ли в нём данные или нет мы не знаем..так ведь?

Comment: filesize() - размер файла. Или 

    $file = fopen('test.txt', 'r');
    if(fgetc($file) === false){
        echo 'Файл пустой';
    } else {
        echo 'Всё гуд';
    }
    fclose($file);

Comment: спасибо за код)). но всётаки подожду, возможно ктото подскажет более правильный вариант. над этим думал, но боюсь что при сбое и неполной записи бэкапа в файл эта защита не сработает. на крайняк так и сделаю)

Comment: При сбое, насколько я понимаю, даже файл не будет создан, если вы его конечно не создаете сами до дампа вручную.

Comment: @Deonis, вообще есть `filesize()` :)

Comment: @Deonis, файл будет создан в любом случае. Упрощенный формат команды:

    mysqldump db_name > db_name.sql

Это переадресация `STDOUT` в файл. Даже если бы `mysqldump` ничего бы в STDOUT не написал, то, все равно, был бы создан файл `db_name.sql` нулевого размера.

Варинты сбоя: либо обрыв связи с MySQL-сервером, либо пренудительный kill процесса. И в первом и во втором случае файл будет создан, но он не будет дописан до конца.

Comment: @Sh4dow, вообще о filesize() я в коментарии сказал. Вы просто не заметили.